# Replace a semicolon followed by a backslash by just a semicolon and dont apply it to other baskslashs alone

Tags: bash, cat, tr

I have a file that contains data that looks like this :

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWW;XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ;EE;/usr/lib/systemd/system/snapd.socket
WWWWWWWWWWWWWW;XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ;EE;/usr/lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target
WWWWWWWWWWWWWW;XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ;EE;/usr/lib/systemd/system/sysinit\target
```

Sometimes errors appear in this file, they look like this ;

```
\WWWWWWWWWWWWWW;\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;\ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ;EE;/usr/lib/systemd/system/sysinit\target
```

As you can see ther is backslashes that makes my file very hard to parse after.

I tried to make them disappeard with :

```
cat ligne.txt | tr "\\" "\0"
```

But it affects the file names containing `\` and I want to keep the file name the same.

So I tried to use the condition only the `\` with a semicolon next to it.

```
cat ligne.txt | tr ";\\" "\0"
```

but it gives me this :

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXZZZZZZZZZZZZZZEE/usr/lib/systemd/system/sysinittarget
```

The data is destroyed.

So i tried this :

```
cat ligne.txt | tr ";\\" ";"
```

but it does this witch is worst :

```
\WWWWWWWWWWWWWW;;XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;;ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ;;EE;;/usr/lib/systemd/system/sysinit;target
```

This brings me to the the question: how does `tr` process `\\` and `;` in parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `sed` :

`cat ligne.txt | sed -e 's/;\\/;/g'`

Comment: You don't need to use `cat` here

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E ':a;s~\\(.*;)~\1~;ta' input_file
WWWWWWWWWWWWWW;XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ;EE;/usr/lib/systemd/system/sysinit\target
```

Comment: While it looks reasonable to me, the OP wants to replace semicolons **followed by a backslash**. You have removed the very first backslah in the line, although it is not preceeded by a semicolon.

Comment: @user1934428 That may very well be a valid point. However, he does also show the format the file currently is which does not have the preceeding semicolon. Hopefully, OP can clarify then I will adjust accordingly. Thanks